# Pass variable from Vue 3 component to another file without using Vuex

Tags: vuejs3

My problem is the following: I need to implement features in someone else's code. This person did not use Vuex, and instead stored global variables in a root object. In component `3dSpace` the variables camera and engine are set.

```
setup(props, { refs }) {

   onMounted(() => {

     let engine = setEngine();
     let camera = setCamera();

 }
}
```

I need those variables in a function in a separate File `ScreenShotFunction`

```
export default function generateScreenShot(root, width, height) {
  //some code

  //I need the variables here
  return BABYLON.Tools.CreateScreenshot(engine, camera, {
     width: width,
     height: height,
 }
}
```

I don't know how I can get `camera` and `engine` into my root object (which is in another file). If there is a solution that would allow me to directly import the variables into my function that would be great. Using vuex to solve the problem would be the last resort. I need to solve this problem quickly, using whatever hacky or anti-patterns are available (the project will be rebuild in the future, I just need to get it to work now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add them to the global window object when the `onMounted` hook is executed.

```
  onMounted(() => {

     let engine = setEngine();
     let camera = setCamera();

     window.engine = engine;
     window.camera = camera;
 }
```

Or do something like this

```
let engine;
let camera;

const setScreenshotDeps = (eng, cam) => {
  engine = eng;
  camera = cam;
}

const useScreenshotDeps = () => {
  return {
    engine,
    camera
  }
}
```

It's hacky but it'll do the trick.
You'll just have to make sure that your `generateScreenshot` function is called after the values have been set otherwise you'll get some issues.